# jQuery tab disable jQuery scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use jqueryUI tabs and want to implement a smooth scroll bar inside each tab. I tried several scrollable plugins like jQuery custom content scroller, TinyScrollbar and now areaaperta NiceScroll, but each time I stack with the same problem - scrollbar works only inside one tab..

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>

    <div id="tabs" style="width:900px; font-size:100%;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" >FIRST</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">SECOND</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">THIRD</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div id="thisdiv">
        <p><b>FIRST SCROLLABLE PARAGRAPH</b>...</p></div></div>

    <div id="tabs-2"><div id="thisdiv2">
        <p><b>SECOND SCROLLABLE PARAGRAPH</b>...</p>
    </div></div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>THIRD TAB </p>
    </div>
</div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(
  function() {     
    $("#thisdiv").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#00F"});
    $("#thisdiv2").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#00F"});  }
);
    </script>
```

Here is jsfiddle that shows that there is no conflicts between UItabs and two scrollbars of niceScroll plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/Fluc/EhcqX/4/

And here I tried to use same divs with scroll bars inside each tab: http://jsfiddle.net/Fluc/cJPT3/2/

As you can see, scrollable works only inside the first tab.. Same with other scrollable plugs..

I'm not jquery programmer but It feels like the problem is related to display property somewhere.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works perfect try and let me know.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    jQuery('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {    
        ui.tab 
        ui.panel
        ui.index
        if (ui.index==0) {
            $("#tabs-1 > .scrollable").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#00F"});
        }else if (ui.index==1) {
            $("#tabs-2 > .scrollable").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#00F"});
        }else if (ui.index==2) {
            $("#tabs-3 > .scrollable").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#00F"});
        } 
  });
});
</script>
```

I have also updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cJPT3/9/

Comment: Now try this one. I have edited my answer and have checked it. this works perfect.